# Is it possible to call a Scala function from Kotlin?

Tags: java, scala, kotlin

I am working on a project which involves Kotlin, Java, and Scala at the same time. In a scenario, I need to execute a Scala function from Kotlin. How can I do it?

Comment: You probably want to add more details like how the **Scala** function looks like, how did you tried to call it, which error you got, what build tool are you using, how is the project structured, etc.

Comment: No, not that thing. btw thanks

Answer (score 4):

The same way you normally execute functions in Kotlin.

Just compile Scala code to bytecode and add it to Kotlin classpath.

Example:

In folder `<classpathFolder>` put:

`ScaTest.scala` :

```scala
class ScaTest() {
    import math._
    def mathFunction(num: Int) = {
        val numSquare = num*num
        (cbrt(numSquare) + log(numSquare)).toInt
    }
}
```

Compile with `scalac ScaTest.scala`

It should produce file `ScaTest.class`

In some other folder create Kotlin file:

`KotTest.kt` :

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val ss = ScaTest()
    println(ss.mathFunction(4))
}
```

Compile with `kotlinc -classpath <classpathFolder> KotTest.kt`

This should produce file `KotTestKt.class`

Run with `kotlin -classpath <classpathFolder> KotTestKt`

Comment: Is pre-compilation necessary, any way I can access scala code at run time?

Comment: Yes, as I said. Compile it and use it in runtime - add a classpath in compile time and then add classpath in kotlin runtime.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the initial comment - Yes, compilation is necessary for compiled languages to work at runtime (or in compile time [here actually api lib might suffice]). Same thing is done in Intellij/eclipse but in background so you don't feel it in any way. This answer depicts what is (more or less) done in that background :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, and example. However, I want to call the scala function before compilation in an android project. Looks like this is not possible.

Comment: @Ray Before compilation scala code is just a text (or abstract syntax tree). In principle you can run scala compiler from kotlin runtime and compile/run what you want. See scala reflection and toolbox https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes

Comment: @Ray You haven't provided enough details so it's not clear why you can't let things go conventionally, i.e. java, scala, kotline see each other's classpaths.

Comment: I managed to communicate with scala from Kotlin using the Receivers.